# Emacs 24.4 cannot load Ergoemacs [Mac OS]

Tags: macos, emacs, emacs24, iterm, ergoemacs

I have problem with emacs and ergoemacs on Mac OS.

What I've done:

1. I installed latest version of emacs (24.4):

> sudo port install emacs

2. Downloaded ergoemacs from http://ergoemacs.org/
   and put it in folder ~/.emacs.d
3. Added to file ~/.emacs:

> (setenv "ERGOEMACS_KEYBOARD_LAYOUT" "us") ; US 
>   (load-file "~/.emacs.d/ergoemacs/site-lisp/site-start.el")

When I tried start emacs, I received an error:

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/Users/%user_name%/.emacs':

Symbol's function definition is void: tool-bar-mode

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.
```

With debug mode:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function tool-bar-mode)
  (tool-bar-mode 0)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-795277> nil "/Users/%user_name%/.emacs.d/ergoemacs/ergoemacs/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 316
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/%user_name%/.emacs.d/ergoemacs/ergoemacs/init.el" "/Users/%user_name%/.emacs.d/ergoemacs/ergoemacs/init.el" nil nil)
  load("/Users/%user_name%/.emacs.d/ergoemacs/site-lisp/../ergoemacs/init")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-459001> nil "/Users/%user_name%/.emacs.d/ergoemacs/site-lisp/site-start.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1432
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/%user_name%/.emacs.d/ergoemacs/site-lisp/site-start.el" "/Users/%user_name%/.emacs.d/ergoemacs/site-lisp/site-start.el$
  load("/Users/%user_name%/.emacs.d/ergoemacs/site-lisp/site-start.el" nil nil t)
  load-file("~/.emacs.d/ergoemacs/site-lisp/site-start.el")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/%user_name%/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 106
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/%user_name%/.emacs" "/Users/%user_name%/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[0 "^H\205\262^@     \306=\203^Q^@\307^H\310Q\202;^@ \311=\204^^^@\307^H\312Q\202;^@\313\307\314\315#\203*^@\316\202;^@\313\307\314\317#\203:^@\320$
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Comment: How do you "start Emacs"?  Could it be that you type `emacs` at the command line, and end up running Apple's way out-of-date and text-only version of Emacs?

Comment: I removed old version (~ 22) and installed new. I type "emacs" in terminal (iTerm).

Comment: @max lipsky, is the problem solved after you install latest emacs?

Comment: Ergoemacs distro haven't been maintained for a couple of years. I recommend just install ergoemacs-mode, or one of the general emacs starter kit, might see http://ergoemacs.org/misc/list_of_emacs_starter_kits.html